# Display node as a popup window

Tags: 7

I am new to Drupal. I have a form which adds details of user to my table. I want to display that node in a popup window. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions for this kind of stuff. I would do it in the theme layer to have something really light. You can also use the variety of popup modules for this. One simple way to do this, use the [Lightbox2 module](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2), checkout this documentation page: http://drupal.org/node/252260

Comment: Great... I am able to do that. But can I porgrammatically close the modal window?? Suppose if I submit the form, can I close the window???

Comment: What form? Is it a node/add form? another Drupal form? or a custom form?

Comment: It is a custom form that I have written in Drupal page. If it passes all the validations it should save the data and close the modal window.

Comment: you need: <script>window.parent.Lightbox.end();</script> http://drupal.org/node/438766#comment-2596092

Comment: You could also use the forms API to do the form: http://thedrupalblog.com/inserting-form-lightbox-window-and-submitting-it-ajax

Comment: I suppose "/node/x/lightbox2" solution doesn't work for D7.

Comment: It should work, you could also use Colorbox: http://drupal.org/node/836160

Comment: I wrote this tutorial awhile back that uses **Magnific Popup**: [Lightbox overlay with Views 3 and Magnific Popup](http://othermachines.com/blog/drupal-lightbox-overlay-views-3-and-magnific-popup)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Colorbox Node](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) module:

> Gives the user the ability to display ANY page inside a colorbox modal without the header and footer. Those pages include:

This is an apt module for pop up a node.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is actually this module:

http://drupal.org/sandbox/yuriseki/1771028

The only think you need to do is adapting the path and you're done!

Comment: Ok... I love the [Node Overlay](https://drupal.org/sandbox/yuriseki/1771028) option except that it requires you give users permissions on your administration settings... not. cool. Does anyone know if this module will be getting updated?

Comment: Link returns a 404 - Page not found

Answer (score 0):

Using colorbox node module to open node content inside the Colorbox.

Download [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) and [Colorbox_node](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) Module from [drupal.org](http://drupal.org) site
You also need to download [colorbox library](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/archive/1.x.zip) and copy to `sites/all/libraries/colorbox`

Install both module and enable it from modules list.
after You should create link either manually or using views or whatever the way you want.
e.g.

```
<a class="colorbox-node" href="node/123?width=600&height=600">Page1</a>
<a class="colorbox-node" href="node/123" data-href="node/123?width=600&height=600">Page2</a>
<a class="colorbox-node" href="node/123" data-inner-width="600" data-inner-height="600">Page3</a>
```

You should specify `width` and `height` of colorbox to fit your content.

**Gallery Support**

```
<a class="colorbox-node" href="blogs/my-example?width=600&height=600" rel="gallery">My Example</a>
```

> Also integrate with Views/Context/Panels Support

Answer (score 0):

### Node pop-up

> Node pop-up module create paths for popup node view without any
>   dependency (only Drupal 7 core functionally used for creation popup
>   window).

https://www.drupal.org/project/npop

> #### HOW TO
>
> 1. Enable module
> 2. Create link.
>
>    1. Variant 1: Set data-npop="NODE_NID" (recomended)
>    2. Variant 2: Set href attribute as "ajax/npop/node/[nid]/load/nojs", where [nid] nid of node and set link
>         class "use-ajax".