# Popup w/overlay for content (Lightbox-esque)

Tags: modal-dialogs, javascript

Is there a module/technique that allows for a popup of a node content?
I'm looking for a lightbox-esque affect that displays specifically content (node?), not an image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display node as a popup window](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/display-node-as-a-popup-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Display node as a popup window](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/display-node-as-a-popup-window/8795#comment-8876)

"There are a lot of solutions for this kind of stuff. I would do it in the theme layer to have something really light. You can also use the variety of popup modules for this. One simple way to do this, is use the Lightbox2 module, checkout this documentation page: http://drupal.org/node/252260"