# Can I use lightbox for displaying pop up biographies?

Tags: 7, javascript

I want to achieve this [effect](http://www.deltaholding.rs/company_overview/board.84.html). When user clicks on (thumb) image, biography and image should pop up. Can I do this with lightbox, and if answer is yes, how to customize it? Also, is there some other module that is good for this purpose? I am using Drupal 7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong or unclear with the question? It would be appreciated to explain what is wrong, every time when you click minus in order to let user know how to fix it. You don't click minuses every time when you don't know the answer.

Comment: @nattan Per the tooltip on the downvote link: _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_. If you'd taken some time to research the problem yourself, and presented a well thought out, interesting question that would be useful to future visitors, and not just solve your immediate, narrowly scoped issue, it probably would have been received a lot better.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about _Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided_, per the [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do this by adding your content as the alt text caption and manipulating the lightbox display with css.

Alternatively this question may help: [load a node content into a lightbox2 (without headers and footer and other blocks)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12925/load-a-node-content-into-a-lightbox2-without-headers-and-footer-and-other-block)

Comment: Have just recently found an extension to the colorbox module that does exactly this! https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node
ENJOY! :)